# Extracting the raw dump file data informations using python numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a use-case to extract the data from a raw dump file. I used `numpy.fromfile` and store it in `numpy` array of `dtype` `uint16` as below:

```
rawData= numpy.fromfile(filename, dtype=np.uint16)
```

In the raw file, the information stored are of different data types. For example `data1` is of `uint64` and `data2` is of `float` and `data3` is of struct (one `uint32` member, array of `float` value of size 5) in raw dump file. Now the question is how to extract the `data1`, `data2` and `data3` information from rawData numpy array of `dtype` `uint16` and print the `data1` and `data2` values in `uint64` and `float` respectively.

Reason why I used the `dtype=np.uint16` in `numpy.fromfile` is that I have lot of other `information` in raw file which is of `uint16`.

[image: Hex]

Comment: You could try  `rawData[n:m].view(uint64')` to a view a subset of the bytes in particular dtype.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't see a question here. Please read [ask].